# ARM register r9 in the Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, cpu-registers, abi

The "ARM Architecture Procedure Calling Standard" (AAPCS/EABI) states (5.1.1) that

```
"The role of register r9 is platform specific."
```

but

```
"A virtual platform [...] may designate r9 as an additional callee-saved
 variable register, v6."
```

The question is: does the Linux kernel use r9 for some special purpose? Or is it used as a normal nonvolatile register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of finding out how the kernel uses it is to simply build a kernel (`CROSS_COMPILE=... ARCH=arm make vmlinux`), and then disassemble the whole thing,

```
${CROSS_COMPILE}objdump -d vmlinux.o | grep 'sb|r9'
```

to check (Using both `r9` and `sb` names as it depends on your objdump what exactly is output).

If you ever find it used in prologue / epilogue code (in instructions like `push {..., r9, ...}`, `stmfd sp!, {..., r9, ...}` or their corresponding `pop`/`ldmfd`) then it's callee-saved. Otherwise, just another scratch reg. The result may depend on your toolchain, kernel config options, or ARM target.

That said, if you compile a Thumb-2 kernel, it will *not* be callee-saved. That's because Thumb-2 `push`/`pop` only operate on the lower reg set (and `lr`/`pc` in a complementary fashion, `push lr` paired with `pop pc`).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I wouldn't do it for vmlinux since it includes the scheduler bits. But a `objdump -DS -M reg-names-std net/core/dev.o | grep push | grep r9` (non-arch code) shows quite some entries, so it's safe to assume that `r9` is a nonvolatile register.

Comment: If you use "-S" in objdump it intersperses the code with source; for a Linux tree, that'll make the output _enormously long_ ... combined with "-D" it disassembles data sections as well (not just code like "-d"), making it even longer. Just "-d", on the other hand, is practical/useful on a Linux kernel.

Comment: I know. But I was doing it on _one_ object file :)

Comment: Thumb2 information is wrong.  Thumb1 (original on ARMv4 and ARMv5) have restriction on register use in Thumb mode.  *Thumb2* (a nebulous concept) which is found on ARMv6 and later has a mixed 16/32bit instruction stream and can save/restore r9.  Also, the question state AAPCS/EABI and this is for non-Thumb1 code.

Comment: Also, the OPs use of this information is wrong.  Just a hit of `r9` in `grep` is not sufficient.  You need to see stack operations.  A correct answer is determined by the compiler and libc; Linux itself can support either.  On a system you could see both.  Just because one binary has stack use of r9 does not mean that the program you build will not use it.  The `objdump`/`grep` combination should be performed on output from your tools.

Answer (score 0):

I think the register definitions are stored in include/asm-arm/ptrace.h

Not sure 100% though...

Comment: Yes, they are there. I don't see anything special about it, but this is not a guarantee. Take PowerPC, for example: ptrace.h has the pt_regs with all GPRs in an array. BUT r2 is the `current()` task in process context :)

Comment: Weird, I was reading an article about it and ARM seems to say that ptrace.h has all the register definitions.  Sorry I couldn't be of any help, but http://infocenter.arm.com might be contain this info.  It might also depend on which ARM processor you're using.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - It depends on the libc and compiler options.  For most ARM Linux distribution, the answer is it is a callee saved register.

Only deeply embedded libcs and tools might use a *static base*.

The linux kernel itself does not use *static base* and r9 is free to use.

It is unclear whether the question is for user processes or for kernel developers.

---

The register `sb` stands for *static base*.  It is a reference to static data (including program globals).  For some systems, you might have multiple *processes* which share the same code, but need different *static base*.  For instance, a network gateway might have a  process for each port with the *static base* containing the state for that port.

As Linux with VM can remap the physical store to a demanded location, it is an alternative to *static base*.  If you ran on an NOMMU system, such as a Cortex-M version of Linux, it is possible that it could use `sb`.  This is not part of the actual OS and Linux's responsibility.  It will just save/restore r9 on context switches.  So the actual answer is that it depends on the *libc*.

It is possible to use *GOT* and other RAM thunks.  But it might be most efficient with NOR flash or ROM in deeply embedded devices to use the *static base*.  For something like a Raspberry Pi, Beagle bone, Android phone, etc.  It will have an MMU and there is no need for the gymnastics of a *static base*.

You may use `objdump -d my_code | grep -E '(sb|r9)'` to determine **STACK** use of r9.  Just a hit of `r9` in `grep` is not sufficient.  You **need** to see stack operations.  On a system you could see both.  Just because one binary has stack use of r9 does not mean that the program you build will not use it.  The `objdump`/`grep` combination should be performed on output from your tools.

A correct answer is determined by the compiler and libc; Linux itself can support either.  You should look at the libc documentation.  In fact, gcc supports the `sb` use by using different options such as,

- -mpic-register=
- -mpic-data-is-text-relative
- -msingle-pic-base

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html

---

U-boot uses a *static base* for instance.  It is quite possible for a static binary to use a static base and other program on the same system to have general purpose `r9` use.  Linux has some nomenclature about ABI use, but is mainly to do with system call mechanics and not register use.

For certain, the Linux kernel will not manage the sb/r9 register.  It would need to be managed and set by the libc loader which would call `map`, `sbrk`, etc to set an initial `sb` before the processes `main()` runs or in the case of a static binary, by program startup code.

See: [Static shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172834/how-to-create-static-linked-shared-libraries) for more technical details.