# Why u-boot can put global data's address into r9 register?

Tags: gcc, arm, u-boot, cortex-a8

When i look through u-boot source code, i found that it pass global data through r9 register like this

```
register volatile gd_t *gd asm ("r9")
```

So, i'm curious, how does u-boot ensure further codes won't use r9 register and corrupt the global data. Is there an options to tell compiler not to use specific register?

Comment: It is also worth noting that it used to be r8, and still is in some vendor branches: http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=commitdiff;h=fe1378a961e508b31b1f29a2bb08ba1dac063155

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Procedure Call Standard for the ARM Architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf):

> The role of register r9 is platform specific. A virtual platform may assign any role to this register and must document this usage. For example, it may designate it as the static base (SB) in a position-independent data model, or it may designate it as the thread register (TR) in an environment with thread-local storage. The usage of this register may require that the value held is persistent across all calls. A virtual platform that has no need for such a special register may designate r9 as an additional callee-saved variable register, v6.

Yet [GCC doesn't have a abi profile for reserving `r9`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html) for platform usage [thus the way u-boot does this is with -ffixed-r9 option](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/denx/u-boot/arch/arm/config.mk#17).

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is -ffixed-reg.  However, if *all* code is compiled with this variable declared as global, then it will never be used for any other purpose (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Reg-Vars.html#Global-Reg-Vars).

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using "volatile" type qualifier here in "register volatile gd_t *gd asm ("r9")"? the memory will be allocated for global data structure and stores the address in gd pointer which is register r9. So the memory address will not be changed asynchronously, the  gcc link provided also says that "Do not use type qualifiers such as const and volatile".

Comment: @user3693586 - I'm not sure I'm the person you should be asking, since I didn't recommend using `volatile`.  That said, it's possible that it will help.  Slightly.  Under certain circumstances.  But since you can't depend upon it (as you point out: the docs are pretty clear), adding it is a bad idea.  People might have expectations that they come to rely upon.  If your code won't work unless it's volatile, your code won't work and you need to do something else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One doubt I have regarding the macro `DECLARE_GLOBAL_DATA_PTR` usage, it is declaring a `gd` variable of type `gd_t`. This macro used in multiple files, means the `gd` variable was declared in multiple files, but still we didn't get `multiple declarations` error for `gd` variable while compiling. From U-boot source, this macro used in `common/cli.c, common/cli_readline.c, common/env_common.c, common/board_r.c`  files and all these files compiled while building.

Comment: "This macro used in multiple files" - Are all of those files used at once?  If one is ARM, one is MIPS and one is x86, there is no conflict because those don't all get compiled into the same output.

Comment: I have built U-boot source and checked. Macro used in multiple files and were compiled. I am referring v2017.3[http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=tree;h=4a7b4aad7ed596a55b7b900c529f5abf41615ab0;hb=8537ddd769f460d7fb7a62a3dcc9669049702e51] source. One such set of files are `common/main.c` and `common/exports.c`. In `common/Makefile` both files are selected as `obj-y += main.o, obj-y += exports.o` , which means they are compiled and part of `built-in.o`. Another set of files are `common/board_f.c` and `common/board_f.c`.

Comment: If we remove register keyword (#define DECLARE_GLOBAL_DATA_PTR volatile gd_t *gd asm ("r9")), then it is giving `multiple definition of 'r9'` error. By using register keyword it is not giving `multiple definition of 'r9'`error. Not sure why this behaviour.