# Shared library for Cortex-M0 device

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm, ld

I would like to ask if anybody knows how to create a shared library that could be accessed from 2 projects. The projects are bootloader and application, they both located at the same Cortex-M0 chip and should compile and work under ARM GCC and ARM MDK. The library is quite big (about ~70k). The language is C.

I am using `extern` declarations, "symdefs" file symbols+addresses (for MDK) and list of PROVIDEs: symbols+addresses (for GCC) to let the linker know about that shared functionality.

The main questions are how to compile that shared library(what options should I use) and how to instruct linker to use that library.

Maybe there is a relative documentation for creating and using a shared library for any of those compilers (for chip applications, not for desktop ones).

I would be grateful if you point me out on that documentation.

Comment: The way to compile is pretty much the same as for the executable. But instead of the linker you should invoke the archiver (`ar`) on your object files in order to pack them into a library.

Comment: As I understand your question, you have some code you wish to be accessible by both the boot loader and the main application.  The name *shared library* has a fairly strict notion in multi-process OSs.  Maybe examine [this question on static linked shared libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172834/how-to-create-static-linked-shared-libraries).  You may simply need to clear out the library BSS and re-initialize the static data when you transition from boot loader to main app.