# arm-gcc: Multiple attribute sections in a .c file

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arm, directive

I am facing an issue in creating multiple sections in a .c file. I wants to place code for task1 in section .task1 and code for task2 in section .task2

Consider the following code:
case 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* Variables for task 1 */
int task1_a;
char task1_b;

/* Variables for task 2 */
int task2_a;
char task2_b;
```

If I use **attribute**  section as below it works fine.
case 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>`
__attribute__ ((section (".task1"))) int task1_a;
__attribute__ ((section (".task1"))) char task1_b;

__attribute__ ((section (".task2"))) int task2_a;
__attribute__ ((section (".task2"))) char task2_b;
```

but what I want is like:
case 3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
__attribute__ ((section (".task1")))
int task1_a;
char task1_b;

__attribute__ ((section (".task2")))
int task2_a;
char task2_b;
```

So that all the time we do not need to write **attribute** ((section (".xyz"))) in front of all the variables or functions.

While compiling case 3 compiler is throwing an error:

```
error: section of 'task2_a' conflicts with previous declaration
int task2_a
```

Is there any way to end the section before starting new section. My understanding is that it should automatically end if we start a new section but it is not happening.

I am using arm-unknown-eabi-gcc version 4.8.4 for compilation.

Comment: `__attribute__` is a part of one declaration only. That's the syntax and you can do nothing about it. Perhaps write some magic macro...

Comment: I have tried to compile your case 3 and no error occured. Maybe you should change your C compiler.

Comment: Why not use 2 `.c` files?

Comment: @a3f I second that.   Section targetting is always super fiddly and toolchain (and even version of toolchain dependent).   Putting things in separate files can simplify the process and make it less quirky.

Comment: Yeah alternative option is to split the code in 2 files but I have seen such code for other platforms like powerpc and mpis. So I wanted to know if this is possible for arm as well.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?  You can not just put everything in one section.  Some data is read/write and other is read-only so the notation you want won't be available.  You can use a macro to make things easier or see [this answer on static shared libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172834/how-to-create-static-linked-shared-libraries/25189092#25189092) which maybe what you want.

Comment: I am creating Memory Partition such that different applications run all together without interference with each other using MMU.