# libc and libgcc in PIC

Tags: c, arm, embedded

Working on some firmware code that needs to be completely position independent. Already have my build system set up, and some initial firmware code that fixes the GOT to the right addresses at runtime. I'm able to link in libgcc and libc, but it doesn't work properly.

Some functions work, like `memcpy`, but `utoa` doesn't correctly reference the `digits` string. Root cause of the problem seems to be that the libs are compiled without fPIC (so base address is zero).

Is there a way to add symbols from the shared library to the GOT?

I'm using *arm-none-eabi-gcc* on Debian, targeting an ARM v7.

Comment: You could compile them yourself.

Comment: You might want to specify if you are position independent code or both code and data.  For static constant data, it can be placed in '.rodata' which would relocate with flash (the 'digits' string).  The '.data' is usually copied by your startup and it can go to the same RAM location.  Unless you have some different requirement.  Also, constant pointer to constant strings are problematic.  I just eliminated them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to recompile libc.a and libm.a to support PIC.  You can query your gcc with '-v' to get the specifics.  Often this will lead to a build record.  For example, I have **gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4** which leads to launchpad and you can find the build logs and exact libc repo used.  Here is another used by the STM32CubeIDE.

https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/10.0/10.3-2021.10

You will need '-fPIE -mno-pic-data-is-text-relative' and '--with-pic' and leave the other libraries build options as per the original.  The 'CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET' can be used to over-ride the defaults.  I use '-mno-pic-data-is-text-relative'; My system had absolute data, but PIC code.  It seems gcc does not support this option.  So, I had to sacrifice `r9` which is always the same.

The newlib is likely hosted at  *git://sourceware.org/git/newlib-cygwin.git*.

It would be nice if the compilers were produced with a PIC multi-lib.  Alas, they are not currently.

> Is there a way to add symbols from the shared library to the GOT?

Sure. You need to compile with PIC/PIE options, or the libraries will not have GOT entries.  Also, you need to write your own linker script.  Just be sure to include the library objects in the GOT section as well.  I added mine to the `.data` section.

```
/* Global offset allows relocation of data. */
_got_address = .;
*(.got)
*(.got*)
_got_end = .;
```

You can use `adr` and `ldr` to perform relocations.

```
/* Relocate got table flash address to runtime */
got_update:
  /* Fixup for runtime address. */
  adr    r0, got_update   /* Run time. */
  ldr    r1, =got_update  /* Link time. */
```

So, the 'GOT' offset is the difference between r0,r1.  If the GOT target was in flash, I added the offset.  But what relocations you need will depend on your system.

I used static libraries, which I guess is your intent as a 'bare metal' application that supports 'over the air' type updates.  In this case, the code can run from multiple locations in NOR/QSPI flash.  There is Q/A on [statically linked shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172834/how-to-create-static-linked-shared-libraries), which might also use PIC mechanics and is much more complex than what I describe above.  For this case, the code might be common, but the data is seperate.

Comment: If this sounds complicated, another alternative is to write your own libc (minimize functionality needed) and compile it.  From recollection, I think the 'libgcc' either had a PIC variant or it was fine.  I have '--specs=nosys.specs', but that maybe standard.  Oh, also use '--nostdlib' to prevent links  to the non-PIC libraries. .... It isn't easy.